# Repainting Dice in a High Low Game

Tags: java

I am setting up a Dice game of High Low and I'm having trouble getting my Dice to repaint or redraw when I press the button that should re-roll the Dice.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DieFrame extends JFrame {

private DiePanel diePanel;
private int die1;
private int die2;
private JRadioButton high;
private JRadioButton low;
private JRadioButton sevens;
private JComboBox amountCombo;
private JLabel balance;
private JButton throwDice;

public DieFrame() {

    diePanel = new DiePanel();
    add(diePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    createControlPanel();
    pack();
}

public void createControlPanel() {

    JPanel betType = createRadioButtons();
    JPanel betAmount = createCheckBox();
    JPanel balanceAmount = createBalanceLabel();
    JPanel diceThrow = createThrowButton();

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        //@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //setRollDice();
            if (throwDice.isSelected()) {
                //diePanel.removeAll();
                diePanel.rolling();
                diePanel.repaint();

            }
        }
    }
    JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();

    ActionListener listener = new ButtonListener();
    throwDice.addActionListener(listener);
    controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    controlPanel.add(betType);
    controlPanel.add(betAmount);
    controlPanel.add(balanceAmount);
    controlPanel.add(diceThrow);

    add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public JPanel createRadioButtons() {
    high = new JRadioButton("High");
    low = new JRadioButton("Low");
    sevens = new JRadioButton("Sevens");

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(high);
    group.add(low);
    group.add(sevens);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    panel.add(high);
    panel.add(low);
    panel.add(sevens);

    return panel;
}

public JPanel createCheckBox() {
    amountCombo = new JComboBox();
    amountCombo.addItem("£1");
    amountCombo.addItem("£5");
    amountCombo.addItem("£10");
    amountCombo.setEditable(false);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(amountCombo);
    return panel;

}

public JPanel createBalanceLabel() {
    balance = new JLabel("Balance=");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(balance);
    return panel;
}

public JPanel createThrowButton() {
    throwDice = new JButton("Throw Dice");
    //throwDice.addActionListener(listener);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(throwDice);
    return panel;
}
}
```

Frame class brings in the buttons. There has been various experimentation in the actionlistener section thus why some stuff is commented out or maybe totally wrong.

```
public class DiePanel extends JPanel {

private int value1;
private int value2;
private static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 400;
private static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 200;

public DiePanel() {
    value1 = new Dice(6).getFaceValue();
    value2 = new Dice(6).getFaceValue();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT));
}

public void rolling() {
    removeAll();
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    DiceFace dice1 = new DiceFace(75, 30, 30, value1); // s, x, y, v
    dice1.draw(g2);
    DiceFace dice2 = new DiceFace(75, 140, 30, value2); // s, x, y, v
    dice2.draw(g2);

}

}
```

DiePanel builds the dice from a DiceFrame and Dice class. I know I need to get a repaint method working in the DiePanel, I'm just not sure how to go about it. I know there are similar questions but I've found nothing useful as of yet.
Everything runs fine. The Dice appear, all the buttons appear just the repaint is doing nothing.
I may be in the complete wrong direction but any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Small Update**

```
void rolling(int dice1, int dice2) {
        value1 = dice1;
        value2 = dice2;
        repaint();
}
```

I have changed the rolling method to the above code.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            //setRollDice();
            throwDice.isSelected();
                //diePanel.removeAll();
                diePanel.rolling(6, 6);
```

And this is in the DieFrame close. This allows me to re-roll the dice once but the output is two sets of six obviously. I'm not sure how to bring in the random die to the Frame. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should separate the data model from the visual model.

Second, the methods that are only used inside a class should be `private`, like the `createControlPanel()` method.

Third, from the data model you extract the information you want to the visual model. You are basically constantly updating the data model when there is a `repaint()` request. Try something like this:

```java
public class DiePanel extends JPanel {

    private static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 200;

    private int value1;
    private int value2;

    private DiceFace dice1;
    private DiceFace dice2;

    public DiePanel() {
        value1 = new Dice(6).getFaceValue();
        value2 = new Dice(6).getFaceValue();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT));
    }

    public void rolling() {
        dice1 = new DiceFace(75, 30, 30, value1); // s, x, y, v
        dice2 = new DiceFace(75, 140, 30, value2); // s, x, y, v
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        dice1.draw(g2);
        dice2.draw(g2);
    }

}
```

I hope that I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help but it just made some of the elements in the output disappear. I have had some minor success in the meantime but am once again stuck.